# How to handle tables with lots of deletes and updates in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance, postgresql-14

I have tables in PostgreSQL 14 database that suffer a lot of deletes and updates every minute, in the following cases:

- A table with many rows that every minute is updated in a specific column;
- A table that serves to store temporary data, thousands of items can be inserted every minute, which will be consulted by an API that will remove them in the next minute, and this cycle is repeated infinitely.

I've already checked the data from the tables and PostgreSQL performs Auto Vacuum and Auto Analyze regularly. But do I need to perform some other type of maintenance on them on a regular basis?
Like:

- `VACUUM FULL ANALYZE`
- Reindex their indexes

My concern is that this amount of operations degrades the performance of the database over time.

Comment: If you validated that auto vacuum has enough chances to cleanup, then things should be fine. You might want to make it more aggressive to keep up with your update rate

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I was worried because I did some tests:
A table with 40M records took 2s - 30s to perform a COUNT of all data.
Already the same database recreated on a new server, it was taking just 700ms to do the count.

And the problem could be being caused because of these operations.

This led me to think that maybe I should apply more VACUUM FULL on the entire database.
And the problem could be being caused because of these operations.

Comment: Your options: a) faster autovacuum b) partitioning c) HOT updates d) change your workload e) use a different database software.